# Displaying graphs of mySQL query results on a web page

Tags: mysql, data-visualization

I understand there are multiple ways to do this -- what  method/language is the easiest for a beginner to learn? I'm up to speed on writing queries and getting the correct results to display in tables on a web page, but need advice on the next step for graphs.  I'm currently using PHP along with mysql.

Thanks!

Comment: This kind of question is OT for SO, but take a look at google's own charts API

Comment: Thanks!  My apologies - this is my first time here so I appreciate your feedback on the question.